# Order of operations after promises

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript (using Node.js) and still learning. I try to wrap around my head with promises and I got into this situation where I don't understand if there is a difference between this code:

```
promiseFunc().then(() => {
     anotherPromiseFunc() // I dont need .then() here, just want to save some data to DB
 });
doSmthElse()
```

and this code:

```
promiseFunc().then(async () => {
     await anotherPromiseFunc() // I dont need .then() here, just want to save some data to DB
 });
doSmthElse()
```

If I don't use `.then()` in the first case, does it mean there is a possibility that `doSmthElse()` will be executed before `anotherPromiseFunc()` is executed? So in order to prevent that, I have to add `async`/`await`? Or all code in `.then()` block is being waited to execute anyway before doing something else?

Note 1: I don't want to chain those promises, because there is more code in my case, but I just simplified it here.

Note 2: I don't use catch because if error will rip through I will catch it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I don't use `.then()` in the first case, does it mean there is a possibility that `doSmthElse()` will be executed before `AnotherPromise()` is executed?

`doSmthElse()` is **guaranteed** to be executed before anything in the fulfillment handler¹ is executed. Promise fulfillment and rejection handlers are always invoked asynchronously. That's true whether you declare the handler function using `async` or not.

For example:

```js
console.log("before");
Promise.resolve(42)
.then(result => {
    console.log("within", result);
});
console.log("after");
```

The output of that is:

```
before
after
within 42
```

> So in order to prevent that, I have to add `async`/`await`?

Where you've added `async`/`await` in your example doesn't change when `doSmthElse()` is executed.

If you want `doSmthElse()` to wait until the promise has been fulfilled, move it *into* the fulfillment handler.¹

If your code were inside an `async` function, you could use `await` instead, like this:

```
// Inside an `async` function
await promiseFunc().then(() => {
    anotherPromiseFunc();
});
doSmthElse()
```

That would do this:

1. Call `promiseFunc()` and get the promise it returns
2. Hook up a fulfillment handler to that promise via `then`, returning a new promise; that new promise is the operand to `await`
3. Wait for the promise from #1 to settle
4. When it does, your fulfillment handler is executed and runs `anothterPromiseFunc()` but **doesn't** wait for the promise it returns to settle (because, as you said, you're not returning that promise from the fulfillment handler).
5. At this point, the promise from #2 is fulfilled because your fulfillment handler has (effectively) returned `undefined`, which isn't a *thenable* (loosely, a promise), so that value (`undefined`) is used to fulfill the promise from #2.
6. Since the promise from #2 has been fulfilled, `await` is satisfied and `doSmthElse()` is executed.

---

¹ the function you pass `then` as its first argument

Comment: FWIW, I go into the details of promises in Chapter 8 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*, and then I go into the details of `async`/`await` in Chapter 9. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: If i would put my ```doSmthElse()``` into .then() after first ```promiseFunc()``` is there any difference between those two examples?

Comment: @VytSer - I'm not sure where you mean you'd be putting it. In the fulfillment handler? Before or after `anotherPromiseFunc()`?

Comment: Crowder - doSmthElse() into fulfillment handler of promiseFunc() in both examples. Would there be a possibility that ```anotherPromiseFunc()``` in first example can be executed after ```doSmthElse()``` anyway? does async/await in second example then make any difference?

Comment: @VytSer- If they're both in the fulfillment handler, they'll be called in the order you call them in. There's nothing random here, no need to speak of "possibilities."

Comment: So in simple words - if I would chain Promises, and those promises would have more promises inside fulfillment handlers, chain would not start to execute next fulfillment handler till all promises in that particular fulfillment handler is not finished executing. Inception of promises in my head, sorry and thank you for informative response JS jedi.

Comment: @VytSer - Let's say we have `p1`, a promise. When you use `p1.then(handlerFunction0`, `then` creates a *new* promise; let's call it `p2`. `p2` won't settle until `p1` settles. Let's assume `p1` is fulfilled. That means your `handlerFunction` gets run. `p2` will be fulfilled or rejected based on what happens in your handler function and what it returns. If an error is thrown in your handler, the `p2` is rejected. If your handler returns a non-thenable value, that value is used to fulfill `p2`. If your handler returns a thenable value (like a promise), `p2` waits for that promise to settle...

Comment: ...and then takes its fulfillment or rejection as its own fulfillment or rejection. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `Promise()` just stands for some function call returning a Promise:

You could say that .then registers an event listener that runs as soon as the promise settles => the task is finished. **It still runs asynchronously** So in your example `doSmthElse` will still run even if the promise hasn't been settled (so if the promise doesn't settle immediately `doSmthElse` will be called **before** the function inside .then)

To let your code run "in order". You would have to use `await` to ensure that `doSmthElse` is called **after** the promise settled or you could put `doSmthElse` into the .then block.